# Migrating windows server 2008

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, sql-server, iis, c#

in less than 9 months Wndows and Sql Server would be not supported and it is urgent to migrate to newest version.
I want to migrate a very critical windows server 2008 to 2016 that runs IIS, DNS Server and SQL Server 2008 .
I want to know that is it safe, Microsoft support backwards compatibility ?
The Application that is run on the server is developed by C#, is it possible that the app stop working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd have to know more details in order to be able to give you an answer that is more than a guess. But...

- DNS -- You should be fine. DNS is a robust enough standard that any clients pointing to your 2008 DNS server will be just fine pointed to a 2016 DNS server.
- IIS -- It depends on your application. Some of the things that came with the IIS version on your 2008 server (or were added to it as additions) might not be installed by default in the version of IIS that installs on a 2016 server. But unless the application does something in particular that has been deprecated, you'll probably be able to get it to work.
- SQL Server -- This depends more on the version of SQL that you'll be using on the new server than it does on the version of the operating system. But again, unless the application does something fairly unusual, it will probably work in a newer version of SQL Server.

This brings up two observations/recommendations.

- Test! -- You'll want to build a new server (or servers; see below) with new versions of the operating system, IIS, and SQL. Test to make sure your application works in the new environment.
- Avoid clown-car servers. -- I highly recommend against running multiple products on the same server. In this case, I'd want IIS and SQL to be on separate servers. And if you can, put DNS on a separate server, too. Brent Ozar has a [good article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/03/ten-ways-tell-sql-server-clown-car/) about clown-car servers.

Comment: Your answer is very good and it gave me good insight to how to prepare a migration plan, it is a good recommendation to separate servers.